# Enable timer for a specific event to be done at an interval in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I am creating a windows service to send mail at specific time intervals.  I want to enable a timer to work a `mail_send()`.

```
private void timer1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // I need a code here to work with email_send()
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(email_send);
}

public void email_send(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("email from");
    mail.To.Add("emailto");
    mail.Subject = DateTime.Now +"logfile";
    mail.Body = "mail with log file attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("F:\\logfile\\logfile.txt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailfrom", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: Formatted code block and fixed english.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your timer by calling method Start() in order to "enable" it.

```
private void timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(email_send);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize the timer

```
public static void Main()
{
InitializeTimer();
timerr.Start();
}
```

You can use the Start and stop to start the timmer and Stop timmer

```
private void InitializeTimer()
 {
  Timer timerr = new Timer();
  timerr.Interval = 5000;
  timerr.Tick += Timerr_Tick;
  }
```

then write tick event.

```
private void Timerr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
         SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
          mail.From = new MailAddress("email from");
         mail.To.Add("emailto");
         mail.Subject = DateTime.Now +"logfile";
         mail.Body = "mail with log file attachment";

         System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
         attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("F:\\logfile\\logfile.txt");
         mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

         SmtpServer.Port = 587;
         SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailfrom", "password");
         SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: timerr.Tick += Timerr_Tick;.this line of code showing error that "no overload  Timerr_Tick delegates event.system.handler"

Comment: thank you . it actually worked. and i want to know how to add specific time intreval in the code. i want to send email at 5:00pm every day. please help me with the problem

Comment: for this purpose u have to use quartz scheduler service which will be crct for your scenrio. http://www.infoworld.com/article/3078781/application-development/how-to-work-with-quartz-net-in-c.html       https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/860893/Scheduling-With-Quartz-Net

Comment: @ShankiyanShanki has it worked for you if its worked then mark it as answer and do a upvote so that it will be helpful for other users